# How do I track different users in CVS?

Tags: java, version-control, cvs

I am using a CVS repo for my java code - I need to give access to this code for a feature that three developers that I am going to hire are going to develop. I don't want them to commit their changes - I just want all three to develop the same feature without changing the base lined code - I am not familiar with CVS (mostly SVN). Do I create folders with developer names? How do I make this happen?

Comment: It is time to switch to [git](http://git-scm.com/).

Comment: whta do you mean by " I am not familiar with CVS (mostly SVN)"

Comment: AmitD - :) will remember that one - how about doing this in CVS?

Comment: @Nishant Never used CVS, just subversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a branch for each one. It will be based on the HEAD version, they will not share code between them and your main version (that would be the HEAD) will not be modified this way.

Comment: creating a branch for each one was what I had in my mind - thought I would ask a question here to understand if it would be a good approach.